# Nested Cell Property: I'm missing something about this proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

This is a paraphrased version of the beginning of a proof given in *The Elements of Real Analysis: Second Edition* By Robert G. Bartle, on page 47.

**Nested Cell Property.** If $n\in\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$
  let $J_{n}$
  be a non void closed cell in $\mathbb{R}$
  and suppose that that this sequence is nested in the sense that 
$$J_{1}\supset J_{2}\supset\cdots\supset J_{n}\supset\cdots$$
  Then there exists an element which belongs to all of these cells.

*Proof*. Suppose that $J_{n}=[a_{n},b_{n}]$
 , where $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(a_{n}\leqslant b_{n})$
 . Thus the set $\{a_{n}\:|\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
  is bounded above by $b_{1}$
  hence the supremum of $\{a_{n}\:|\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
  exists, let $u=\sup\{a_{n}\:|\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
 . Then we have that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(a_{n}\leqslant u)$
 . The claim is that $u\leqslant b_{n}$
  for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
 . Otherwise, $(\exists i\in\mathbb{N})(b_{i}<u)$
 . Since $u=\sup\{a_{n}\:|\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
  there must exist a $a_{k}$
  such that $b_{i}<a_{k}$ .

I don't see how we get this last inequality. $a_{k}\leqslant u$
  and $b_{i}<u$
 , but nothing forces $a_{k}=u$, 
  so why is it necessary that $b_{i}<a_{k}$? The rest of the proof is clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each fixed $m$, $b_m$ is an upper bound for the set $\{a_n:\ n\in \mathbb N\}$. Thus by definition $u\leq b_m$. Or using your line of argument, if $b_i<u$ for some $i$. Let $\epsilon >0$ such that $b_i < u - \epsilon < u$. Then by definition of $u$, there is $a_k$ such that $a_k > u- \epsilon > b_i$.

Comment: Thanks! It took a while but the light bulb finally switched!

Comment: @Ishfaaq: The argument fails when the intervals are open. It is because $u\leq b_n$ does not imply that $u\in (a_n , b_n)$. For example, $a_n = -1/n$ and $b_n = 0$. Then $u \leq 0$ but $u$ is not in $(-1/n, 0)$.

Comment: @Ishfaaq In the definition of the Nested Cell Property we required that $J_n$ be a *closed* non-void interval. Your proposed counter example is a good example of why we require the cells to be closed.